# Deduce that the metric is not complete.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Consider the upper half plane with Riemannian metric $g_{11}=1, g_{12}=g_{21}=0, g_{22}=1/y$. Prove that the length of the vertical segment from $1$ to $\epsilon$ tends to $2$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. Deduce that the metric is not complete.

Length=$\int_{\epsilon}^11/\sqrt{y}  \;dy=2(1-\sqrt{\epsilon})$. So the limit is $2$. But, how could I use this fact to prove the incompleteness? In particular I wanted to construct a cauchy sequence that is convergent to $0$, but the thing is, I can deal with this kind of stuff if I was given the Euclidean metric, but how do I deal with Riemannian metric here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you may take all points $x_n$ corresponding to $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n+1}$ as a cauchy non-converging sequence.

Comment: Ya I know, but how do I prove it is cauchy with respect to Riemannian metric?

Comment: Using $lim_{n\to \infty}d(x_{n+1},x_n)=0$

Comment: Note that the $y$ axis is a geodesic and so the distance between two points on this line is just difference between their corresponding distances from $1$.